# Ubuntu crontab runs skript but it doesn't work

Tags: cron, raspberrypi

I'm pretty new to linux, ubuntu etc. and I have a pretty simple skript in my raspbian lite crontab (or sudo crontab, it didn't matter) installed that looks like this:

```
# stops server, updates server, reboots raspberry    
0 3 * * /home/pi/minecraft/restart.sh
0 6 * * /home/pi/minecraft/restart.sh
0 9 * * /home/pi/minecraft/restart.sh
0 15 * * /home/pi/minecraft/restart.sh
0 21 * * /home/pi/minecraft/restart.sh

# autostart server, autostart discord bot
@reboot /home/pi/minecraft/start.sh
@reboot /usr/bin/forever start /home/pi/bot/mcbot.js
```

And neither of those execute for some reason, but when I check `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` it says that it ran them:

```
Feb  7 22:12:20 raspberrypi cron[317]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Feb  7 22:12:20 raspberrypi cron[317]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Feb  7 22:12:20 raspberrypi CRON[386]: (root) CMD (/home/pi/minecraft/start.sh)
Feb  7 22:12:20 raspberrypi CRON[387]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/forever start /home/pi/bot/mcbot.js)
Feb  7 22:12:20 raspberrypi CRON[333]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb  7 22:12:20 raspberrypi CRON[335]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

The thing is that on my old SD card this skript worked.
Today I set up a clean reinstall on a new and faster SD card and followed, as far as I know at least, the exact same steps.

Does anyone have a suggestion why it's not working?

Comment: `cron` ran `/home/pi/minecraft/start.sh`, and ran `/usr/bin/forever start /home/pi/bot/mcbot.js`, but this command produced output, maybe an error message. The `No MTA installed, discarding output` messages are `cron` trying to email you this output, and failing. Look for a file named `dead.letter`, which will contain the output. I would guess that you did not install ALL of the things `mcbot.js` needs to run.

Comment: I just set up postfix and was able to remove those last 2 CRON [333] [335] lines.
Looking at `sudo tail -f /var/mail/root` showed that the bot did run this time and actually started, since I found and corrected a small typo, but the server didn't....
This just got more complicated I think

Answer (score 0):

Never mind actually I got it working SOMEHOW, but now it run a bugged version of both the discord bot and the server, so I have to do some more troubleshooting now apparently...